# Doing two SELECT query, with the second query dependant of the first, and the result of the second being concatenated in one

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have those two tables:

```
+----------+ +---------------+
|tGathering| |tGatheredPeople|
+----------+ +---------------+
|cId       | |cGatheringID   |
|cPlace    | |cPeople        |
|...       | +---------------+
+----------+
```

I want in one select query to retrieve data about Gatherings in one Place (say "Berlin, Germany"), and amongst the values, would be a comma-separated string of all the people present at one gathering.

Is it possible to do it in one query? And if yes, how does one call this kind of query (as you may have noticed, I had difficulties defining what I was searching for)?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why are you string concat'ing the values of the second? SQL is really good at working with sets, not so good with things like string concat. You'ld do better to export the lists to something like PHP and then echo in a forloop.

Comment: @drachenstern: Well I wanted to do a concatenation, because I didn't know that what you describe could be possible. Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @Eldros ~ I could, but that's really a SO question. In short, you would get the recordset into PHP, then for(int counter=0;counter<recordset.count;counter++) {returnstring.=','.recordset[counter][column];} and then echo returnstring

Comment: I think this is more of a developer than a DBA question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [GROUP_CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

An example usage would be:

```
SELECT tGathering.*, GROUP_CONCAT(people.cPeople SEPARATOR ',') FROM tGathering
INNER JOIN tGatheredPeople AS people ON `people`.cGatheringID=`tGathering`.cId
GROUP BY people.cGatheringID
```

Comment: With a few correction, I made it worked. (Notably using `people.cPeople SEPARATOR ','` in the GROUP_CONCAT and using the table aliases on the ON and GROUP BY clauses.)

Comment: awesome. it was free-handed from memory. I'll update the answer with the changes. It should be noted that `SEPARATER ','` is not necessary, as that's the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do in one query, as long as you prepare the list of PeopleByPlaceId in a function that you would apply to each place Id.
Something like:

`Select t.*, PeopleByPlaceId(t.CId) as ListOfPeople`

`from TGathering t`

In the function you would build the concatenated list of people names.

How to do this without using a function.. I don't know :-).